# Changing a language in the middle of a python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, pyhook

I have a program which processes text using pyhook.
Since I also use Hebrew I tried seeing what will happen if I type in Hebrew. It seems like if when the program starts the PC is on Hebrew also if I change my language it will understand it as Hebrew and vice-versa with English. I also looked at what the Ascii value for the Hebrew letters comes out as and it seems to be wrong also by the Hebrew Ascii and also by the Unicode numbers..
Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
global start
global text
print text
text += chr(event.Ascii)
print event.Ascii
```

*the prints are there for checking up*
Thank you

Comment: "Hebrew American Standard Code for Information Interchange" isn't a thing. Do you mean the Windows [code page 1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255)? There's a lot of of information missing here. What does "seems to be wrong" mean? What were you expecting, and what was the result? It's hard to help without any of that information.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this code page, thank you. But if so it's still peculiar that it isn't capable of writing in English and that pressing "Shift-Alt" doesn't change the language inside the program.

Comment: are you trying to low-level process text input from the keyboard? cause you should really be a unicode expert to do that... `text += chr(...)` most certainly is not what you want. I recommend http://www.benfrederickson.com/unicode-insanity/ to understand just some of the problems that approach has

Comment: AFAIK, under the default settings, Shift-Alt on Windows only changes your keyboard layout. It has no effect on anything else. If your program doesn't understand Hebrew input, it's not the fault of the keyboard layout. (Your program doesn't understand Hebrew input because it seems to think there's a thing called Hebrew ASCII)